# puppeteer issue on CentOs 7 problem after exactly 30 minutes

Tags: node.js, centos7, puppeteer

i have a script that use node js and puppeteer, the script run wonderful on my windows 10 for as long as i dont close it from command line, when i`m using it .

on my VPS it is working for exactly 30 minute , i tried few times and all the time it is exactly 30 minutes, the node js is still functioning but no data is received after 30 minutes, i`m scraping web socket just for the info .

i have tried any args on launch but nothing is keep the connection alive.

Comment: It's not my cup of tea, but it sounds settings-related. If it's not your own VPS, I would suggest contacting the support, they might fix that for you in no time.

Comment: the problem is that i dont know exactly where is the problem , nodejs, puppeteer or my vps, im controlling the VPS but what can it be that make this issue is the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a solution :)
i guess the sites checking your activity and if you are not active for 30 minutes then they closing any connection that is open , so with puppeteer you can use mouse movement and that is the solution , i put movement in interval and all are fine now, if someone have that issue then just use this method and all are good.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the websocket connection yourself to bypass the issue? Not sure the application here, but a simple "disconnect - reconnect" every 29 minutes (or every minute for that matter) might just do the trick?

Comment: i wish i knew how to do that , can you show my some direction? thanks

Comment: after using my script to scrape other site this issue is the same even on my windows machine , i guess its something with pinging the websocket , when looking at the frames in chrome i  see that every 15 seconds it sends a message/frame to the server so i guess this is the problem , so the questions is there something that i can do in puppeteer to send a message to the socket, in chrome its send 2 and get back 3 every 15 sedonds :)